# Why are type conversions expensive?

Tags: c#, .net

Why are type conversions expensive? What does a type conversion entail?

Okay, I get it for value types but let's exclude them for a moment. Let's just talk about casts between reference types. If I write this:

```
class Animal { }

class Dog : Animal { }
```

**Example 1**

```
var dog = new Dog();

object obj = dog;
```

**Example 2**

```
public Animal GetAnimal()
{
    return new Dog();
}

object obj = GetAnimal();
```

How many type conversions do the above examples contain and why are they expensive?

I understand that it's only a new 4-byte pointer that has to be allocated on the thread's local argument stack and the object reference of the newly created reference pointer points to that same old address. Why is this an expensive thing to do? Is allocating a new object reference CPU intensive? Then even copying same object references must entail that cost, like in the below example:

```
Animal fish = new Animal();

Animal anotherFish = fish;
```

That must be equally expensive then?

Comment: Please define "expensive"... what makes you think they *are* expensive?

Comment: @JonSkeet: That's a part of my question, really. The whole argument for generics or generic types is that they avoid the cost related to type conversions. And I realized I've been taking that without giving it much thought. I assumed until now that it was expensive in the sense that it involved more CPU time.

Comment: One clarification. With [Conversion Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx), "classes or structs can be converted to and/or from other classes or structs, or basic types". In contrast, with [casts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx): "A cast operation between reference types does not change the run-time type of the underlying object; it only changes the type of the value that is being used as a reference to that object. For more information, see [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)."

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2, are you thinking about boxing/unboxing by any chance?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: Well for value types, generics avoids boxing and unboxing. Even for reference types, it avoids the cost of *checking* an explicit cast. But that's certainly not "the whole argument" for generics. It's mostly (IMO) about being able to make your code express your intention more clearly.

Comment: @dkozl Not particularly. I can totally appreciate the extra CPU effort involved in boxing/unboxing because they are conversions from/to value and reference types. I just want to know, for example, if I put only reference types in an `ArrayList`, why is it still considered inferior to `List<T>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you. That would be it, I imagine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I just realized that I used the phrase, "the whole argument for generics." Sorry, I didn't mean to say that at all. I think I used it because as a English-as-a-Second-Language speaker, we tend to use cliche's and stock phrases sometimes instead of taking the time to *really* say what we want to. We do that, if not for the whole sentence, for at least parts of it. I guess even people who have English as their first language do it. In fact, I think they tend to do it more often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casts to a base type are always free at runtime. When you write:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
object obj = dog;
```

The JIT sees:

```
void* dog = new Dog();
void* obj = dog;
```

The JIT does not particularly care about the different reference types in this case. To it, all ref types are just pointers. The JIT is perfectly capable of dealing with trivially redundant variables and assignments.

A cast to a derived class often has a runtime cost because a runtime check must be made. This can sometimes be optimized out. If a check is actually necessary, it looks a little like this:

```
object obj = new Dog();
AssertCastValid<Dog>(obj);
Dog dog = obj; //Invalid C#, but OK for the JIT internally
```

With `AssertCastValid` being code to verify the runtime type. Here's what it *could* look like (although it probably doesn't):

```
bool AssertCastToDogValid(object obj) { return obj.GetType() == typeof(Dog); }
```

(This is incorrect, but illustrates the idea.)

As you can see, upcasts are always free and downcasts are often not free. How expensive? That's relative to what else you have going on in your code and it depends on the exact case (depth of hierarchy, cast to interface, ...).

Comment: Thank you, @usr. Then variant generic types must incur the same cost, right?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 everything that you do with generic types is statically guaranteed to succeed at runtime (think about it - what operation could fail? There are none.). Everything that is statically safe does not need runtime checks. Generics do have a cost over non-generic code, but it does not lie in casts.